# Error con version "build" de flutter

Tags: flutter, sqlite

He estado creando una pequeña aplicación en Flutter desde hace un tiempo. Es simple y solo utiliza las extensiones SQLite y la adaptación de Windows/Linux, sqflite_common_ffi, para el almacenamiento de datos. Tengo un problema al "construir" el código con "flutter build windows --release". Todo parece estar correcto, puedo ejecutarlo siempre que esté dentro de la carpeta de Flutter. Sin embargo, al mover la carpeta "windows" al escritorio, la aplicación ya no puede crear o acceder a su base de datos.

Al generar esta versión, no se presenta ningún error en PowerShell.